# Changing the default vertex colour

Tags: python

I would like to change the default vertex colour to red for a specific procedure using python. Changing the size seems simple enough by using this script.

C.preferences.themes['Default'].view_3d.vertex_size = 5

Is there a way to change the colour?

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy

c = bpy.context.preferences.themes['Default'].view_3d.vertex
c.r = 1  # red
c.g = 1  # green
c.b = 1  # blue

#['__doc__', '__module__', '__slots__', 'act_spline', 'bl_rna', 'bone_locked_weight', 'bone_pose', 'bone_pose_active', 'bone_solid', 'bundle_solid', 'camera', 'camera_path', 'clipping_border_3d', 'edge_bevel', 'edge_crease', 'edge_facesel', 'edge_seam', 'edge_select', 'edge_sharp', 'editmesh_active', 'empty', 'extra_edge_angle', 'extra_edge_len', 'extra_face_angle', 'extra_face_area', 'face', 'face_back', 'face_dot', 'face_front', 'face_select', 'facedot_size', 'frame_current', 'freestyle_edge_mark', 'freestyle_face_mark', 'gp_vertex', 'gp_vertex_select', 'gp_vertex_size', 'grid', 'handle_align', 'handle_auto', 'handle_free', 'handle_sel_align', 'handle_sel_auto', 'handle_sel_free', 'handle_sel_vect', 'handle_vect', 'lastsel_point', 'light', 'normal', 'nurb_sel_uline', 'nurb_sel_vline', 'nurb_uline', 'nurb_vline', 'object_active', 'object_origin_size', 'object_selected', 'outline_width', 'paint_curve_handle', 'paint_curve_pivot', 'rna_type', 'skin_root', 'space', 'speaker', 'split_normal', 'text_grease_pencil', 'text_keyframe', 'transform', 'vertex', 'vertex_active', 'vertex_bevel', 'vertex_normal', 'vertex_select', 'vertex_size', 'vertex_unreferenced', 'view_overlay', 'wire', 'wire_edit']
```